# unknown error when compile STLPort with arm-linux-gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, stlport

I was trying to compile STLPort with cross-compiler toolchaine for uclinux. 
**According to INSTALL in root folder of STLPort library, if you want add new toolchaine, then you must find most nearest toolchaine and modified for your compiler.**
I select gcc.mak and change gcc to arm-linux-gcc and c++ to arm-linux-c++. I got this error when compile :

```
.../../src/num_get_float.cpp:44:6: #error Unknown endianness.
../../src/num_get_float.cpp: In function `double stlpmtx_std::_Stl_atod(char*, 
   int, int)':
../../src/num_get_float.cpp:728: error: 'struct _ll::<anonymous>' has no member 
   named 'hi'
../../src/num_get_float.cpp:729: error: 'struct _ll::<anonymous>' has no member 
   named 'lo'
../../src/num_get_float.cpp:736: error: 'struct _ll::<anonymous>' has no member 
   named 'hi'
../../src/num_get_float.cpp:737: error: 'struct _ll::<anonymous>' has no member 
   named 'lo'
```

what is this error? how can I make a appropciate Makefile for STLPort on arm-linux-gcc?

**EDIT** : Error is fixed by first answer but I have another error : 
When I try to compile the code, the makefile gets me this sentences : 
*** ATTENTION! *** 
This makefile tries to use system locale which might not work well with all glibc  flavours.
If build fails, please resort to gcc.mak which will build C-locale only version for STLport
and in the end I got this errors for c_local.c:

```
In file included from c_locale.c:32:
arm-linux-gcc -I../stlport -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -D_STLP_USE_GLIBC -D_STLP_REAL_LOCALE_IMPLEMENTED -O2 -fpic c_locale.c -c -o ../lib/obj/GCC/ReleaseD/c_locale.o
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Find_locale':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:118: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_decimal_point':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:242: error: `DECIMAL_POINT' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:242: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:242: error: for each function it appears in.)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_thousands_sep':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:246: error: `THOUSANDS_SEP' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_grouping':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:250: error: `GROUPING' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_int_curr_symbol':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:289: error: `INT_CURR_SYMBOL' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_currency_symbol':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:292: error: `CURRENCY_SYMBOL' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_mon_decimal_point':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:295: error: `MON_DECIMAL_POINT' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_mon_thousands_sep':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:298: error: `MON_THOUSANDS_SEP' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_mon_grouping':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:301: error: `MON_GROUPING' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_positive_sign':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:304: error: `POSITIVE_SIGN' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_negative_sign':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:307: error: `NEGATIVE_SIGN' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_int_frac_digits':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:310: error: `INT_FRAC_DIGITS' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_frac_digits':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:313: error: `FRAC_DIGITS' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_p_cs_precedes':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:316: error: `P_CS_PRECEDES' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_p_sep_by_space':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:319: error: `P_SEP_BY_SPACE' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_p_sign_posn':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:322: error: `P_SIGN_POSN' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_n_cs_precedes':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:325: error: `N_CS_PRECEDES' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_n_sep_by_space':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:328: error: `N_SEP_BY_SPACE' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_n_sign_posn':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:331: error: `N_SIGN_POSN' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `_Locale_ctype_create':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:485: error: `_NL_CTYPE_TOLOWER_EL' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:487: error: `_NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER_EL' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c: In function `cname_lookup':
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:526: error: `_NL_CTYPE_NAMES_EL' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:531: error: `_NL_CTYPE_HASH_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function)
c_locale_glibc/c_locale_glibc.c:532: error: `_NL_CTYPE_HASH_LAYERS' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [../lib/obj/GCC/ReleaseD/c_locale.o] Error 1
```

I think this error is related to attention of makefile.
What can I fix the problem? what is **resort for gcc.mak** in attendtion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the endianness of the ARM processor you want to run uclinux on. Then you can try running `gcc -D_STLP_BIG_ENDIAN ...` or `gcc -D_STLP_LITTLE_ENDIAN ...` in your Makefile to get past this error.